# Obtengo error "list out of range" en Python, pese a que mi arreglo esta inicializado y la posición existe

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un arreglo "A" en python, inicializado con 7 enteros. lo que busco es sustituir los valores de "A" con los de otro arreglo "B". Lo anterior, dentro de un for loop. He impresó el areglo para asegurarme de que "A" contiene las posiciones esperadas. Sin embargo, obtengo un error "list out of range". Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
k=3
sequence=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def rotate(arr,k):

    rotated=[]
    rotated=[0 for i in range(7)]
    print(rotated)  #efectivamente imprime una lista [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    k= k % len(sequence)
    position=k
    for i in sequence:
        if position  < len(sequence):
            rotated[position] = sequence[i] #aqui ocurre el error. position=3 y rotated 
 #tiene efectivamente la posicion 3. No deberia estar fuera de rango.

            position = position + 1
        else:
            position = 0
            rotated[position] = sequence[i]
            position = position + 1
    
    return rotated
```

Comment: ¡Lo que quieres hacer sería equivalente a `return arr [k+1:] + arr[:k+1]` ?

Comment: El código está incompleto. Falta la invocación para ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema lo tienes en el `for`.

Le estás pidiendo el `dato` que hay en `sequence` mientras que quieres pedirle la posición que tiene en la lista.

Puedes cambiarlo por algo como `for i in range(len(sequence)):`

o puedes utilizar `enumerate`

`for i, v in enumerate(sequence):` con lo que obtienes tanto el indice en la lista como el valor.

Ahora fíjate que en la función le llegan dos datos

`def rotate(arr,k):`

Pero en ningun momento utilizas la lista `arr`, estás utilizando `sequence` como variable global.

siguiendo tu código queda:

```
def rotate(arr, position):
    rotated = [0] * 7
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        if position < len(arr):
            rotated[position] = v 
            position = position + 1
        else:
            position = 0
            rotated[position] = v
            position = position + 1

    return rotated


k = 3
sequence = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

res = rotate(sequence, k)
print(res)
```

Pero en python podría quedar:

```
def rotate(arr, position):
    return arr[position+1:] + arr[:position+1]
```

`arr[position+1:]` devuelve a partir de la posición indicada.

`arr[:position+1]` añade al final de la nueva lista el principio de la lista que nos envían.

Comment: Gracias. Efectivamente cambiar el for i in range(len(sequence)) soluciono mi problema.